# Finding the list of common children (descendants) for any two nodes in a cyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, cyclic-graph

I have a cyclic directed graph and I was wondering if there is any algorithm (preferably an optimum one) to make a list of common descendants between any two nodes? Something almost opposite of what Lowest Common Ancestor (LCA) does.

Comment: In a cyclic graph, a node can be a descendent of itself.

Comment: You don't really have descendants in a cyclic graph. You're looking for the set of vertices that are reachable from both source vertices?

Comment: Do you mean "a list of common **adjacent** nodes"?

Comment: Simply conduct a DFS on both nodes and choose the intersection of the respective sets of nodes.

Comment: @Andrew_CS: No. I am particularly looking for the all common nodes which are reachable from any two (or more) number of nodes.

Comment: I don't think there are much better solutions than enumerating all the reachable nodes from A and B using DFS and calculating the intersection. You can introduce some optimisation: if you're looking for the nodes reachable by A and stumble into B, you can stop looking and just list everything reachable from B.

Comment: @Biziclop: So, it is gonna be a very heavy process. Since I am gonna repeat it for all the nodes and get the intersections for multiple subset of them.

Comment: If one of the nodes is fixed, you can simplify the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user1990169 suggests, you can compute the set of vertices reachable from each of the starting vertices using DFS and then return the intersection.

If you're planning to do this repeatedly on the same graph, then it might be worthwhile first to compute and contract the [strong components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) to supervertices representing a set of vertices. As a side effect, you can get a topological order on supervertices. This allows a data-parallel algorithm to compute reachability from multiple starting vertices at the same time. Initialize all vertex labels to `{}`. For each start vertex `v`, set the label to `{v}`. Now, sweep all vertices `w` in topological order, updating the label of `w`'s out-neighbors `x` by setting it to the union of `x`'s label and `w`'s label. Use bitsets for a compact, efficient representation of the sets. The downside is that we cannot prune as with single reachability computations.

Comment: You can't treat vertices not in the intersection as visited. Imagine this graph A -> D and B -> C -> D (with A and B being your sources). D is reachable from B but only through C, which has to be traversed first.

Comment: You can however avoid calculating the intersection if one source is found to be reachable from the other.

Comment: @biziclop If you have more than 2 inputs (OP hinted at that in a comment) then you might still have the find the intersection at the end, but it would save running the search algorithm on one of the nodes since they would have the same reachable nodes.

Comment: @Andrew_CS Not the same, but one will contain the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a DFS ([depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)).

```
For each input node
    Create a collection to store reachable nodes
    Perform a DFS to find reachable nodes
        When a node is reached
            If it's already stored stop searching that path // Prevent cycles
            Else store it and continue

Find the intersection between all collections of nodes
```

*Note:* You could easily use BFS ([breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) instead with the same logic if you wanted.

---

When you implement this keep in mind there will be a few special cases you can look for to further optimize your search such as:

- If an input node doesn't have any vertices then there are no common nodes
- If one input node (A) reaches another input node (B), then A can reach everything B can.
    This means the algorithm wouldn't have to be ran on B.
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reverse the direction of the edge and use LCA?

Comment: Do you know that will work, and are just stating your answer as a question?  Then you should make your answer more authoritative.  Or are you not sure, and just going from OP's question?  Then this should be a comment, not an answer.